# Finding a Machine_ID when the pressure value is the same for many consecutive rows

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks a bit like this (but with hundreds of thousands of rows)

[image]

What I want to be able to do is find the Machine_ID and Run_ID where the pressure value is the same 3 consecutive times. so in my example I should be able to get Machine_ID = 1 and Run_ID = A1 because 234 appears 3 times consecutively. While with Machine_ID = 2 the values are repeated mostly twice in the same run so it shouldn't appear on my result.

I'm not sure on how to do this. I thought about creating a new column that is called Next_Pressure_Value where it shows you the Pressure_Value underneath and then create an extra column that is calculated by saying Pressure_Value - Next_Pressure_Value and then if the value is 0 I know that it didn't change. The problem is that this only helps me find if two values are the same. I just don't know how to do that for 3 or more consecutive values (In reality I might have to see if maybe 15 of them are continuously the same)

Can somebody help me figure out a strategy to find this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(time, 2) over (partition by machine_id, run_id order by time) as next_time_2,
             lead(time, 2) over (partition by machine_id, run_id, pressure_value order by time) as next_time_2_pressure_value
      from t
     ) t
where next_time_2 = next_time_2_pressure_value;
```

What this does is look head to the time value two rows ahead for each machine and run.  Then, it does the same thing for each machine, run, *and* pressure.  If these are the same, then the intervening values are all the same.